# Terraform - refactoring modules: Error: Provider configuration not present

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules

I'm refactoring some Terraform modules and am getting:

```
Error: Provider configuration not present

To work with
module.my_module.some_resource.resource_name its
original provider configuration at
module.my_module.provider.some_provider.provider_name is required, but it
has been removed. This occurs when a provider configuration is removed while
objects created by that provider still exist in the state. Re-add the provider
configuration to destroy
module.my_module.some_resource.resource_name, after
which you can remove the provider configuration again.
```

It seems like I need to remove that resource from the tfstate file then re-add it with the new tf config.

As I'm refactoring some monolithic code there are hundreds of these `Error: Provider configuration not present` messages.

Any shortcut to removing and re-adding?

Comment: if you don't need to handle the existence of the resource you can modify the state directly with: `terraform state rm module.my_module.some_resource.resource_name`

Comment: This HashiCorp troubleshooting article gives two scenarios and their solutions. https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500000332721-Error-Provider-configuration-not-present

Answer (score 84):

As the error message explains, Terraform has detected that there are resource objects still present in the state whose provider configurations are not available, and so it doesn't have enough information to destroy those resources.

In this particular case, that seems to be occurring because there is a `provider` configuration block in one of your child modules. While that is permitted for compatibility with older versions of Terraform, [it's recommended to only have `provider` blocks in your root module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/module-providers.html) so that they can always outlive any resource instances that the provider is managing.

If your intent is to *destroy* the resource instances in `module.my_module` then you must do that before removing the `module "my_module"` block from the root module. This is one unusual situation where we can use `-target` to help Terraform understand what we want it to do:

```
terraform destroy -target=module.my_module
```

Once all of those objects are destroyed, you should then be able to remove the `module "my_module"` block without seeing the "Provider configuration not present" error, because there will be no resource instances in the state relying on that provider configuration.

If your goal is to move resource blocks into another module, the other possible resolution here is to use `terraform state mv` to instruct Terraform to track the existing object under a new address:

```
terraform state mv 'module.my_module.some_resource.resource_name' 'module.other_module.some_resource.resource_name'
```

Again, it's better to do this *before* removing the old module, so that the old provider configuration remains present until there's nothing left for it to manage. After you've moved the existing object into a new module in the state and have a `resource` block in place for it in the configuration, Terraform should understand your intent to manage this resource with a different provider configuration from now on and you can safely remove the old `module` block, and thus the `provider` block inside it.

Comment: The `terraform mv` command is now `terraform state mv`. See https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/mv.html

Comment: `-target` flag was all what I needed. You saved me.

Comment: What if we want to preserve the resource as-is, and instead just use a different provider?  I haven't found a solution for this other than manually editing the state file.

Answer (score 7):

You can comment out resources temporary in the module which you want to destroy, uncomment resources on recreation and you can follow the below steps to avoid the error.

Remove the provider from the module and Pass provider in the module explicitly,

```
module "pass_provider" {
  source = "../module"
   providers = {
    aws = aws
  }
}
```

Pass provider with alias,

```
module "pass_provider_alias" {
  source = "../module"

   providers = {
    aws = "aws.alias_name"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I started to get this *Provider configuration not present* error after upgrading Terraform v0.12 to **v0.13**.

Following [explicit-provider-source-locations](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-13.html#explicit-provider-source-locations) to align with Terraform v0.13 should probably be the right way, but for the meantime, **downgrading to v0.12** has resolved it.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to check, if you are working in a team, is to validate the last version of terraform used to build, if your version is other change it and test.  A Example of this kind of issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/26062

Comment: This should be higher ranked. This was the real reason in my case.

Comment: For future people: run terraform plan & apply, even if 0 things change. This will force the tf version of the state file to update & then the misleading error goes away.

Comment: That fixed it for me! Very misleading error. My local TF was `1.5.7` while the CI one was `1.7.4`.

Answer (score 3):

If you commented out/removed a module and you see this error then another option is `terraform state rm` to esentially forget about it. [Terraform state rm](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/state/rm.html)

You definately want to destroy the resource, `terraform destroy -target=module.mymodule` but in some cases the resource isn't physical, for example a `random` within the module. Also if you are using Terraform Cloud and the workspace is VCS linked then you wont be able to run an `apply` or `destroy` locally. In these cases use `rm` and if there are lingering resources just delete them manually.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue in a development environment while refactoring my monorepo to add multiple environments (staging, prod). I was using Terraform Cloud. I solved it by destroying everything that Terraform was tracking, doing the refactor, and then doing a new `plan`/`apply` from scratch. This won't work for most situations, but it was by far the easiest solution for me since there were 100+ resources that had moved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked for me is just removing orphan resources from the `.tfstate` file manually.

`terraform init` -> `terraform plan -out=my.plan` -> `terraform apply my.plan` worked well after that