# Terraform Module throw provider configuration not present when modifying

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules

I have a standalone module that previously used [implicit provider inheritence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393294/terraform-refactoring-modules-error-provider-configuration-not-present#implicit-provider-inheritance#implicit-provider-inheritance). I now need to [pass the providers explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393294/terraform-refactoring-modules-error-provider-configuration-not-present#implicit-provider-inheritance#passing-providers-explicitly). As I need to reference resources in multiple regions. After making the change to the module, before publishing it, if I run `terraform validate` then I get several `Error: Provider configuration not present` errors.

```
│ Error: Provider configuration not present
│ 
│ To work with aws_api_gateway_method.function_proxy_root its original provider configuration at
│ provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].env is required, but it has been removed. This occurs when a provider      
│ configuration is removed while objects created by that provider still exist in the state. Re-add the provider configuration
│ to destroy aws_api_gateway_method.function_proxy_root, after which you can remove the provider configuration again.
```

I have read [Terraform - refactoring modules: Error: Provider configuration not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393294/terraform-refactoring-modules-error-provider-configuration-not-present). However, I don't believe this is my problem. As this is a standalone module, so there is no state for it to reference. I must not understand something; as I cannot see how Terraform can know that I have made the change.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've shared it seems like you are trying to use `terraform validate` directly with a module that is designed to be called from another module. You've asked Terraform to validate it as a *root* module, and so Terraform is reporting that this module is not valid to use as a root module because it expects a calling module to pass it a provider configuration, but there is no calling module in this case.

(The error message is admittedly confusing for this situation. Terraform *thinks* that on a previous run you had a `provider "aws"` block in this module because for a root module that would be the only way for this module to have been valid. Terraform doesn't know that this module has never been used as a root module before, so it's making an incorrect assumption when deciding how to describe this problem.)

If you want to validate a module that is intended to be called from another module, a typical solution is to create a development-time-only root module that exists only for you to validate and test your module in isolation.

For example, you could make a subdirectory `test` and place in it a `test.tf` file containing the following source code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
}

module "main" {
  source = "../"

  # ...

  providers = {
    aws.env = aws
  }
}
```

You can then validate your shared module *in the context of this stub root module* like this:

- `cd test`
- `terraform init` (to initialize the test directory as a root module working directory)
- `terraform validate` (to validate the entire configuration all together, including both this stub root module *and* the main module you want to validate)

Terraform should then see that your root module is passing a `hashicorp/aws` provider configuration into the `aws.env` configuration slot declared by the shared module, and therefore consider this overall configuration to be valid.

A bonus benefit of this approach is that you can also perform *other* operations using that `test` subdirectory, such as running `terraform plan` assuming that you have suitable environment variables set to allow configuring the `hashicorp/aws` provider, so that you can try out your module in isolation before you update other configurations to use it.